# How to get the number of pages of current wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I do split the `$post_content` using  `<!--nextpage-->` as separator, but maybe there is another method to obtain the number of pages of a single post because I'm doing it many times on large posts.

The [WP_Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) class doesn't have a member like `$post_pages` or something.

Comment: You can use 'posts_per_page' attribute.

Comment: @PPL that doen't work because it applies to `WP_Query` function that returns a list of posts... I'm talking about a single post with pages separated by `<!--nextpage-->`

Comment: Please check my answer and replay your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for a link to previous posts with directional:

```
<?php previous_post_link(); ?>
```

Or this for a link to previous posts that without "<<":

```
<?php previous_post_link('<strong>%link</strong>'); ?>
```

The code needs to be inside the loop.

Or

```
<div class="prev-posts pull-left">
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
if($prev_post) {
   $prev_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $prev_post->post_title));
   echo "\t" . '<a rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_title. '" class=" "><strong><<< &quot;'. $prev_title . '&quot;</strong></a>' . "\n";
                }
?>
</div>

<div class="next-posts pull-right">
<?
$next_post = get_next_post();
if($next_post) {
   $next_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $next_post->post_title));
   echo "\t" . '<a rel="next" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '" title="' . $next_title. '" class=" "><strong>&quot;'. $next_title . '&quot; >>></strong></a>' . "\n";
                }
?>
</div>
```